# jest TypeError: undefined is not iterable

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I using jest for running my unit test but I am getting an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getVideoTracks')
```

Any suggestions on how to test the below line in jest

```
[videoTrack] = (await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})).getVideoTracks();
```

My unit test file -

```
import { Track } from './Track';
import { } from '../index';

const mockMediaDevices = {
    getUserMedia: jest.fn()
};

Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
    writable: true,
    value: mockMediaDevices,
});

Object.defineProperty(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia, 'getVideoTracks', {
    writable: true,
    value: jest.fn(),
});

describe('Track', () => {
    describe('applyConstraints()', () => {
        let track: Track;
        let videoTrack: MediaStreamTrack;

        beforeEach(async () => {
            [videoTrack] = (await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })).getVideoTracks();
            track = new Track(videoTrack as MediaStreamTrack);
        });

        it('should have applyConstraints method', () => {
            expect(typeof track.applyConstraints).toEqual('function');
        });
    });
});
```

Detailed Error -

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getVideoTracks')

      67 |
      68 |     beforeEach(async () => {
    > 69 |       [videoTrack] = (await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})).getVideoTracks();
         |                                                                                 ^
      70 |       track = new Track(videoTrack as MediaStreamTrack);
      71 |     });
      72 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (Media/Track/Track.test.ts:69:81)
```

I have tried this code -

```
const mockMediaDevices = {
  getUserMedia: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ getVideoTracks: jest.fn() })
};
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
  writable: true,
  value: mockMediaDevices,
});
```

But this gives an error -

```
TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

      73 |
      74 |     beforeEach(async () => {
    > 75 |       [videoTrack] = (await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})).getVideoTracks();
```

Comment: Your test double returns undefined, the default for a Jest mock function, _not_ an array of at least one element that can be destructured to videoTrack.

Comment: @jonrsharpe after changing o this also it's not working.. `const mockMediaDevices = {
  getUserMedia: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ getVideoTracks: [jest.fn()] })
};

Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
  writable: true,
  value: mockMediaDevices,
});`

Comment: @jonrsharpe, can you please guide me how to fix this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change this code:

```
const mockMediaDevices = {
    getUserMedia: jest.fn()
};

Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
    writable: true,
    value: mockMediaDevices,
});

Object.defineProperty(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia, 'getVideoTracks', {
    writable: true,
    value: jest.fn(),
});
```

to (EDITED v2)

```
const mockMediaDevices = {
  getUserMedia: () => Promise.resolve({
    getVideoTracks: () => [jest.fn()],
  }),
};

Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
  writable: true,
  value: mockMediaDevices,
});


beforeEach(async () => {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
  [videoTrack] = stream.getVideoTracks();
  track = new Track(videoTrack as MediaStreamTrack);
});
```

because when you destruct your `getVideoTracks()` result you choose the element at 0 index. But `jest.fn()` is not an array that can be destructed as `[videoTrack] = (await ....`

Comment: Hi Thanks for comment, but after changing this, I am getting error - `TypeError: (intermediate value).getVideoTracks is not a function or its return value is not iterable`

Comment: Oh, yes. I missed that `getUserMedia` is a function. I've edited the first example

Comment: I am only using this code - `const mockMediaDevices = {
  getUserMedia: () => ({
      getVideoTracks: new Promise(res => res(jest.fn())),
  }),
};

Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
  writable: true,
  value: mockMediaDevices,
});` but same error - `TypeError: (intermediate value).getVideoTracks is not a function or its return value is not iterable`

Comment: `getVideoTracks` is also a function right ? but errro says `TypeError: (intermediate value).getVideoTracks is not a function or its return value is not iterable` or line ` [videoTrack] = (await navigator.... ` is the problem any suggestions

Comment: I've edited the code one more time (new changes also touches `beforeEach` func). If you get the same error, try to set a breakpoint on line with this code `[videoTrack] = stream.getVideoTracks();` and check what is in the `stream` variable.

Comment: it's the same as you edited earlier,  after debugging I see stream is - `console.log
    stream  {
      getVideoTracks: Promise {
        [Function: mockConstructor] {
   
          getMockName: [Function (anonymous)]
        }
      }
    }`

Comment: error - `TypeError: stream.getVideoTracks is not a function or its return value is not iterable`

Comment: @JavascriptCoder Omg, I forgot to remove Promise from getVideoTracks mock)) Edited the answer. It should work now)

Comment: Hi plus one for your answer. It seems that problem is solved.. `TypeError: videoTrack.getCapabilities is not a function` I guess I have to mock `getCapabilities` now..

Comment: Thank you. Yes, everything needed should be mocked. I'd rather recommend you to create a class MediaStreamDouble (or sthing like this) that will contain all the methods you expect

Comment: Sorry to ask again, `TypeError: videoTrack.getCapabilities is not a function` for mocking this `const mockMediaStreamTrack = {
  id: '04b14bc2-2c0e-4c54-9e9d-1d52f7a34c5f',
  kind: 'audio',
  muted: true,
  label: 'sample',
  contentHint: 'sample',
  enabled: true,
  readyState: 'live',
  stop: (): void => {
    /* placeholder */
  },
  getCapabilities: (): void => {
    /* placeholder */
  }
};

const mockMediaDevices = {
  getUserMedia: () => Promise.resolve({
    getVideoTracks: () => [jest.fn().mockReturnValue([mockMediaStreamTrack])],
  }),
};` is it correct,

Comment: Try to return an array of  media stream tracks:
`const mockMediaDevices = {
  getUserMedia: () => Promise.resolve({
    getVideoTracks: () => [mockMediaStreamTrack],
  }),
};`